# How to search for string in Python by removing line breaks but return the exact line where the string was found?

Tags: python, string, file, keyword

I have a bunch of PDF files that I have to search for a set of keywords against. I have to extract the exact line where the keyword was found. I first used xpdf's pdf2text to convert the file to PDF. (Tried solr but had a tough time tailoring the output/schema to suit my requirement).

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
searched_string = sys.argv[2]
result = [(line_number+1, line) for line_number, line in enumerate(open(file_name)) if searched_string.lower() in line.lower()]

#print result

for each in result:
    print each[0], each[1]
```

> ThinkCode:~$ python find_string.py sample.txt "String Extraction"

The problem I have with this is that for cases where search string is broken towards the end of the line :

> If you are going to index large binary files, remember to change the
>   size limits. String
>
> Extraction is a common problem

If I am searching for 'String Extraction', I will miss this keyword if I use the code presented above. What is the most efficient way of achieving this without making 2 copies of text file (one for searching the keyword to extract the line (number) and the other for removing line breaks and finding the keyword to eliminate the case where the keyword spans across 2 lines).

Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Note: Some considerations without any code, but I think they belong to an answer rather than to a comment.</del>

My idea would be to search only for the first keyword; if a match is found, search for the second. This allows you to, if the match is found at the end of the line, take into consideration the next line and do line concatenation only if a match is found in first place*.

**Edit:**

Coded a simple example and ended up using a different algorithm; the basic idea behind it is this code snippet:

```
def iterwords(fh):
    for number, line in enumerate(fh):
        for word in re.split(r'\s+', line.strip()):
            yield number, word
```

It iterates over the file handler and produces a (line_number, word) tuple for each word in the file.

The matching afterwards becomes pretty easy; you can find my implementation [as a gist on github](https://gist.github.com/1115208). It can be run as follows:

```
python search.py 'multi word search string' file.txt
```

There is one main concern with the linked code, I didn't code a workaround both for performance and complexity reasons. Can you figure it out? *(Spoiler: try to search for a sentence whose first word appears two times in a row in the file)*

* I didn't perform any testing on my own, but [this article](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) and the [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation) suggest that string concatenation is not that efficient in python (don't know how actual the information is).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the github contribution. The only issue is that it is case sensitive and if there are multiple instances of keywords int he same line, then the second keyword is shown as found in the next 2~3 lines for some reason! Debugging it, will let you know what I find!

Comment: The new revision is case-insensitive, regarding the bug you found, the problem is that when a match for the first keyword is found, the iterator advances and one of the successive keywords does not match, the search is continued from the current position and not from the next word after the first match.

Comment: Actually, I am extracting the text for each keyword - so multiple instances aren't an issue! I will have to check your new iteration for case sensitive fix. The only other issue is the special symbol - if the search string has a symbol, like '(Search String' or 'String)', it is not matching 'Search String' or 'String'. Strip them off at regex? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can perform query string manipulation at line 20 and words manipulation between line 7 and 14.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the coding help! Made minor changes to suit my requirements : https://gist.github.com/1119047

Comment: Remember to compile the regex (both of them actually), you will notice some great speed improvements I think.

Comment: When I integrate it with MySQL code though, I am not getting similar results! Can you pl take a look at my code : https://gist.github.com/1119047 It searches for a list of keywords against a directory of text files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way of doing it, but my suggestion would be to start by taking in two lines (let's call them `line1` and `line2`), concatenating them into `line3` or something similar, and then search that resultant line.

Then you'd assign `line2` to `line1`, get a new `line2`, and repeat the process.

Comment: Thank you. That will be (n-1) concatenations. I like the approach but is it the most efficient/pythonic approach? I will eventually have to resort to this approach of yours if I don't find a better way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: And what if the keywords spawn three lines? :)

Comment: @GaretJax : My keywords are limited to 3 words at most but good thinking!

Comment: @ThinkCode: Is there something that prevent a line containing a single word?

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `re.MULTILINE` when compiling your expressions: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

Then use `\s` to represent all white space (including new lines).

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` has nothing to do with it. That simply changes the behavior of `^` and `$` in regex patterns. Also, it should be `\s+` rather than just `\s`, just in case there are multiple line breaks (as in the example provided).

Comment: re.compile('search\s*string', re.DOTALL) ?

Comment: @ThinkCode: `re.DOTALL` isn't needed either, because you wouldn't be using `.` in your search string. Also, you should probably use `\s+` rather than `\s*`, as the latter will also cause `searchstring` to be matched. I was actually thinking of suggesting a regex solution as well, but for some reason I assumed you'd prefer to do it line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks again! Looks like a regex solution will decrease the no. of search ops but I don't know how to adapt a regex solution to my problem here, any leads?